# Why is the root node in a stack of trees overwriting other root nodes in the stack?

Tags: c++, tree, stack

I have created a push down stack of pointers to trees. The program stores equations as trees when the user types in a equations in postfix (i.e. as below)

34*7+ 58+ 12* would equal

```
   ----+----        ---+---      ---*---
   |        |       |     |      |     |
---*---     7       5     8      1     2
|     |
3     4
```

However at the moment any attempt to store a tree of more than one node (when + or * is encountered) overwrites the previous trees i.e. the above equation leads to the following stack:

```
 ---+---      ---+---       ---*---
 |     |      |     |       |     |
 1     2      1     2       1     2
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char info; struct node *r, *l;
};


class Stack
{
    private:
        node *stack;
        int p;
    public:
        Stack (int max = 100)
            { stack = new node[max]; p=0; }
       ~Stack ()
            { delete stack;}
        inline void push(node item)
            { 
                stack[p] = item;
                p++;
            }
        inline node pop()
            { 
                p--;                
                return stack[p];
            }
        inline int empty ()
            { return !p; }
};

void tree(const char *ltr)
{
    struct node *z;
    Stack stack(50);
    z = new node;
    z->l =z; z->r =z;z->info='a';
    while(*ltr)
    {
        while (*ltr == ' ')
        {
            ltr ++;
        }
        struct node *x;
        x = new node;
        x ->info = *ltr; 
        if ( (*ltr == '+' || *ltr == '*') && !stack.empty())
        {
            x->r=&stack.pop();
            x->l=&stack.pop();          
        }else{
            x->l = z; x->r = z;
        }
        stack.push(*x);
        ltr++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char word[100];
    cin.get(word, 100);
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    tree(word);
    cin.get();
}
```

It appears to be that when x->r = &stack.pop(); is executed it overrides all previous node->r. However node->info is untouched, and the z nodes do not affect the tree either.

Would anyone know what is going on I've been trying to work out what is going on and what I've done wrong for a few hours now.

Kind Regards
Sam

---

**Amendment**

To test the code I've been using a non recursive traverse type function (recursion due to the issue lead to stack overflow) the code for this is a bite messy but I've included it below, if you run this and enter:

12+ 34* 56+

you'll see the problem that I have, it should say:

aa5+ aa3* aa1+

but instead produces:

aa5+ aa5* aa5+

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char info; struct node *r, *l;
};

void traverse3(struct node *tree)
{
    {
        cout << tree->info;
    }
}
void traverse2(struct node *tree)
{
    {
        traverse3(tree->r);
        cout << tree->info;
    }
}
void traverse1(struct node *tree)
{
    {
        traverse2(tree->r);
        cout << tree->info;
    }
}

void traverse(struct node *tree)
{
    {
        traverse1(tree->r);
        cout << tree->info;
    }
}

class Stack
{
    private:
        node *stack;
        int p;
    public:
        Stack (int max = 100)
            { stack = new node[max]; p=0; }
       ~Stack ()
            { delete stack;}
        inline void push(node item)
            { 
                stack[p] = item;
                p++;
            }
        inline node pop()
            { 
                p--;                
                return stack[p];
            }
        inline int empty ()
            { return !p; }
};

void tree(const char *ltr)
{
    struct node *z,*c;
    Stack stack(50);
    z = new node;
    z->l =z; z->r =z;z->info='a';
    while(*ltr)
    {
        while (*ltr == ' ')
        {
            ltr ++;
        }
        struct node *x;
        x = new node;
        x ->info = *ltr; 
        if ( (*ltr == '+' || *ltr == '*') && !stack.empty())
        {
            x->l = &stack.pop();
            x->r = &stack.pop();
        }else{
            x->l = z; x->r = z;
        }
        stack.push(*x);
        ltr++;
    }
    c = new node;
    int q;
    for(q=0; q<3; q++)
    {
    *c = stack.pop();
    traverse(c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char word[100];
    cin.get(word, 100);
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    tree(word);
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Should it be `x->l=&stack.pop()` after `x->r=&stack.pop()`?

Comment: Since you appear to have 3 separate trees, just wondering, how will this equation be resolved? What will be done with the three separate trees?

Comment: Ahh I'm very sorry that was a mistake when I uploaded the code, I was messing around and undid a few too many changes before I posted the code really sorry.

Comment: Zetta,        I initially was trying to generate a method of building and storing a single tree to represent an equation using a stack (out of theoretical interest) however I started getting unexpected results and so I reduced the problem as much as possible tried to solve it but got no where.